# Can't inserting radio button data from php to databse

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Ok! so i am not an expert in PHP . I cant get my radio button data to be inserted into "gender" column in the database.

**Register.php**

```
<label for='gender' >Gender*: </label><br/>



 <input type="radio" name="genderf" id="genderf" value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('gender') ?>'maxlength="50"/> Female
<input type="radio" name="genderm" id="genderm" value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('gender') ?>'maxlength="50"/>Male
```

and the **fgmembersite.php** is this im just inserting the function code whch will collect the data from the register.php to database

```
function CollectRegistrationSubmission(&$formvars)
    {
        $formvars['name'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['name']);
        $formvars['gname'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['gname']);
        $formvars['age'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['age']);
        $formvars['gender'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['genderm']);
        $formvars['gender'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['genderf']);
        $formvars['school_college'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['school_college']);
        $formvars['class_section'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['class_section']);
        $formvars['stream'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['stream']);
        $formvars['phone_number'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['phone_number']);
    $formvars['username'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['username']);
        $formvars['email'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['email']);
        $formvars['password'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['password']);

    }

 $insert_query = 'insert into '.$this->tablename.'(
        name,
        gname,
        age,
        gender,

        school_college,
        class_section,
        stream,
        phone_number,
        email,
        username,   
        password,
        salt,
        confirmcode
        )
        values
        (
        "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['name']) . '",
        "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['gname']) . '",
        "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['age']) . '",
        "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['gender']) . '",

        "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['school_college']) . '",
        "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['class_section']) . '",
        "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['stream']) . '",
        "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['phone_number']) . '",
        "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['email']) . '",
        "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['username']) . '",
        "' . $encrypted_password . '",
        "' . $salt . '",
        "' . $confirmcode . '"
        )';  




There are no errors or exceptions , just the gender column is empty in spite of checking the radio button.
```

Answer (score 0):

for radio inputs the `name` should be the same, as you can only select one. in your case `gender`

```
 <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderf" value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('gender') ?>'maxlength="50"/> Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderm" value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('gender') ?>'maxlength="50"/>Male
```

i dont know what `$fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('gender')` renders but you jut want **m** and **f** by the looks of it

then you use `$_POST['gender']`

```
$formvars['gender'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['gender']);
```

I would add there are more than 2 genders.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $formvars['gender'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['genderm']);
    $formvars['gender'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['genderf']);
               ^^^^^^
```

Anything sent via the `f` radio button will overwrite the `m` radio button, because your arrays keys are the same.